# Is there a solution to get the full response from a gpt model?

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api, langchain, llama-index

I am trying to train a gpt model using openai api and langchain in order to make a chatbot on my custom data, I have prepared my data in txt format and when the user ask a question get the response correctly but I am facing a problem which is the answer isn't complete how could I handle this?

I tried to change the model, and I tried to increase the variables value and didn't work

Here is my code

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTSimpleVectorIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper, ServiceContext
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
import os

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "MYAPI"

def construct_index(directory_path):
    # set maximum input size
    max_input_size = 4096
    # set number of output tokens
    num_outputs = 2000
    # set maximum chunk overlap
    max_chunk_overlap = 20
    # set chunk size limit
    chunk_size_limit = 600 

    # define prompt helper
    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input_size, num_outputs, max_chunk_overlap, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit)

    # define LLM
    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.5, model_name="text-davinci-003", max_tokens=num_outputs))
 
    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path).load_data()
    
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper)
    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context=service_context)

    index.save_to_disk('index.json')

    return index

construct_index("context_data/data")

def ask_ai(query):
    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.load_from_disk('index.json')
    response = index.query(query)
    return response.response

@app.route('/<question>')
def answer_question(question):
    answer = ask_ai(question)
    return answer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone at [community.openai.com](https://community.openai.com/t/use-continue-in-chatgpt-api/230368) says:

> If you resend what you received, it should likely continue, but it
> will cost more tokens…